# Remove array from javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, checkbox

**Context**

I'm trying to implement a feature so that when the user clicks on a checkbox within a table, the attribute `value` and `data-title` of the checkbox should be stored in a JS object literal named `selected` as a new key-value pair array element.

In case the user clicks a second time on the same checkbox, the corresponding array element should be removed.

**Issue**

The first time a checkbox is clicked, an array is created in object `selected` as intended.

However, when the same checkbox is clicked a second time, instead of removing the corresponding array, **a new one (repeated) is added**.

**Code**

```
var selected = {items:[]};     
$('#table').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
    var found = false;
    $.each(selected.items, function(i, val) {
        if (val.key == $(this).attr("value")) {
            selected.items.splice(i ,1);
            found = true;
            return false; //step out of each()
        }
    });

    if (found == false) {
        selected.items.push({key: $(this).attr("value"), value: $(this).attr("data-title")});
    }

    console.log(selected);
});
```

Comment: Why not make it depend on the `checked`  state of the checkbox? I assume your array should represent the boxes that are currently checked.

Comment: It's likely an issue with `val.key == $(this).attr("value")`. This likely (possibly due to the strangeness of equality in Javascript), never returns true. You should probably use [===](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons) aswell. [Debug your javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code) and check this

Comment: Nicely written question BTW, well done. If only every low rep user was this considerate

Comment: What is `this` equal to inside the `$.each` callback?

Comment: Just rebuild the array. Other option is to check the checked state. If checked, do what you are doing. If unchecked loop and find the match and remove that index.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the wrong context of `this` inside `each`. it is no longer the element in the click handler

Try

```
$('#table').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
    var found = false;
    var value = $(this).val();// store value from `this` before entering `each`
    $.each(selected.items, function(i, val) {
        if (val.key == value) {
            selected.items.splice(i ,1);
            found = true;
            return false; //step out of each()
        }
    });
    ....
```

Comment: That's exactly the root cause of the problem.

Comment: @Sam32 should definietly use `===` as liam pointed out. I didn't want to change your code a lot...just point out the *"why"* which is more important sometimes than learning all new ways to do it and not getting to root of original problem

Answer (score 3):

First, I would recommend to use a key-value-pair object, as it is way easier for lookups.

```
var selected = { items : {} };
```

this way you would access your selected items using

```
selected.items[my.key]
```

maybe somethink like this...

```
var selected = {items:{}};     
$('#table').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
    var checked = $(this).is(":checked"),
        title = $(this).data("data-title"),
        value = $(this).val();

    if (checked && !selected.items[value])
        selected.items[value] = title;
    else if (!checked && !!selected.items[value])
        delete selected.items[value];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this one:

```
var selected = { items:[] };

$('#table').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
    selected.items = $('#table input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function(){
        return {
            key: $(this).attr('value'),
            value: $(this).attr('data-title')
        }
    }).toArray()
});
```